# Failed to ioctl on specific disks

Tags: c++, linux, ioctl, sector

I used /proc/diskstats to get the number of sectors read and wrote. 
I want to convert this number to bytes so I look for the sector size.
I used [How to find floppy\ CD sector size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127119/how-to-find-floppy-cd-sector-size-in-linux) to get the sector size of disks sda, sda1 and sda2 but it fails with the following errors:
failed ioctl on file /dev/sda with error Invalid argument
failed ioctl on file /dev/sda1 with error Inappropriate ioctl for device
and the same for sda2.
Will appreciate your help.
Thanks

```
          struct hd_driveid id;
          string fileName = "/dev/";
          fileName += diskName;
          int fd;

          fd = open(fileName.c_str(), O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
          if (fd < 0) {
              LogError("Cannot open file " << fileName);
          }
          else
          {
              if (ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &id) < 0) {
                  LogError("failed ioctl on with error " << strerror(errno));
              } else {
                  currBytesPerSector = id.sector_bytes;
              }
              close(fd);
          }
```

Comment: I've edited the code in the question you linked to, it was invalid and passing a wild pointer around.

Comment: I already did the change for me before and it still didn't work.

Comment: Is it related to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103065/why-do-i-get-hdio-get-identity-failed-message-when-booting-with-external-usb-h)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `ioctl` doesn't always work for certain types of block devices, but, more importantly, this value is *not* the actual sector size as reported in `/proc/diskstats`.

the diskstats code return the number of sectors read, where sectors are sized from the value returned from `BLKSSZGET`:

```
    int sector_size = 0;
    int err = ioctl(fd, BLKSSZGET, &sector_size);
    if (err > 0) {
        currBytesPerSector = sector_size;
    }
```